# Moving only bitmap inside an ImageView

Tags: android

I have an ImageView with a black background set in xml, and in code I'm placing bitmap with `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

You can select between `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` and `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`.

If `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` is selected, bitmap is smaller than the ImageView, and the black background is visible.

I would like to move only bitmap across the screen. I tried with this code, but it moves whole ImageView, not only bitmap inside ImageView.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - 50;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - 100;
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to only move bitmap that's inside ImageView?

Also I would like to increase and decrease width and height of a bitmap and maintain the bitmap's aspect ratio.

I tried with this, but it's not working:

```
buttonIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = (int) ((layoutParams.width + 10) * scale + 0.5f);
                layoutParams.height = (int) ((layoutParams.height + 10) * scale + 0.5f);
            }
        });
```